# Two confirm dialogs when deleting

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have a `CMenu` code that fires two confirmation dialogs when I try to delete an item.

This is how my `CMenu` code looks like:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'List things', 'url'=>array('list')),
        array('label'=>'Delete thing', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array(
            'submit'=>array(
                'delete',
                'id'=>$model->thingID
            ),
            'confirm'=>'Are you sure?'
        )),
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'class'=>'divided'
    )
));
```

Am I missing something in this code? Why is the confirmation dialog firing twice?

EDIT:

The problem is caused by something inside skel-panel, but I'm not able to find out what exactly is causing it. Any ideas how to disable a href tracking in skel-panel?

EDIT 2:

I found where the problem is coming from, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thing is skel-panel is wrapping the entire `body` inside a div. Weird thing is that it strats handling clicks on all `hrefs` apparently.

The `initObjects` function is the one that wraps everything (here https://github.com/n33/skelJS/blob/master/src/skel-panels.js )

EDIT 3:

Ok, I found the bug. It's caused somewhere in jQuery and it got fixed between 1.8.3 and 1.9.0.

Where can I get a detailed log of bugs/fixes/patches between those two version so I can cherry-pick only the change I'm interested in? (as I just can't afford the required amount of time to upgrade to jQuery 1.9.x)

Comment: I copied that code into `actionView()` of my models, and it worked fine, alerted only once

Comment: So you mean it alerts twice in `actionAdmin()` only.

Comment: In all the actions I have tried so far, it alerts only once.

Comment: You are right, the bug is caused by something fishy in skel-panels (a JS library).

Answer (score 1):

I think it appears twice because a call to `delete` from a `CMenu` already fires the dialog automatically. Try removing the

```
'confirm' => 'Are you sure?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this happened to me once.. I don't remember why.

- Do you, by any chance, have **more than one delete button on the same page?**
- Do you have **any other element** that may have the same ID as the delete button (Yii sometimes gives default IDs to elements like `Yw0` and `Yw1` and so on but sometimes because of the way you build your view, it may give two elements the same ID so maybe you would get two actions because there would be two listeners 'listening' for the click or change event).

If you do, you may need to add an **unique id** to each so that one click doesn't fire more than one event (that is, events for the other delete buttons).

Try this:

```
...
),
  'id' => uniqid('foobarbaz'), 
  'confirm'=>'Are you sure?'
)),
...
```

Comment: There is only 1 delete button, but I tried the ```id``` thing too, same result. The message keeps showing twice.

Comment: But are there two menus? Maybe another link that, when clicked, triggers a submit action? The thing here is that Yii assigns names like `yw0`and `yw1`to widgets so that each has a different name but sometimes it doesn't work... Just make sure there isn't another element (maybe in a grid, for instance) that may be also listening for a `click` event. It looks like there's two functions listening on the event, that may be why you're seeing two alerts.

Comment: Ok, I'll check if there are more items, but iirc there is just that CMenu with just 2 items (one link and one link with delete action).